# $ not defined but jQuery IS defined in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

What might cause Firefox to tell me $ is not defined, but using 'jQuery' works as expected.

I'm on Wordpress 3.4 and Wordpress comes packaged with jQuery.  Is it something specific to Wordpress?

Comment: Would a moderator care to tell me why my comment was deleted?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Huh? I have no idea what your deleted comment was. I posted mine for Jim, independently.

Comment: @Blazemonger Lol my apologies. I left the same "accept your previous answers" comment and mine was deleted by some random admin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) has been called. To resolve this with a minimum amount of code change do this.

Before:

```
$("your").code(function () {
  $("that").uses($.all("over").the("place"));
});
```

After:

```
(function ($) {
  $("your").code(function () {
    $("that").uses($.all("over").the("place"));
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you ever get the feeling that your computer is... talking to you?

Comment: @Blazemonger No, because there is very probably *other* code that relies on `$` not being `jQuery` (otherwise there'd be no reason to use `noConflict()` in the first place). Your suggestion would fix one bit of code and break the other.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery works in noConflict mode inside wordpress as the docs state: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that useful bit of info!